# How to get notification payload data when app is in received notification in Background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully received notification when the app is in Background But Notification callback method **didReceiveRemoteNotification** is not called in iOS 11 for using Swift4. I want to get notification payload data when the app is in the received notification in Background. I am sending notification using firebase console. When the app is open **willPresent** is called. But in Background no any method called
I am using code:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
    {
        print(userInfo)
         saveNotificationDetail(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
func notificationIntegrate(application: UIApplication)
    {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
        Messaging.messaging().delegate=self
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotification),
                         name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
    }
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        saveNotificationDetail(userInfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)

    }
}
```

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned here.. https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e

Answer (score 2):

There might be some problem with the configuration setting in push notification. Verify the below steps:

**1. Check whether you enabled `remote-notifcation` and `background-fetch` for your application in `Capabilities` tab.**

[image]

**2. The push notification payload consists of `content-available` key:**

> The key content-available is a new feature, and it is this key that makes silent push possible.
>
> *You enable with content-available=1. But, it is WRONG to disable with content-available=0. To disable, you have to REMOVE the key in the payload.*

Also, verify if following keys are present in your payload

```
{
  "aps": {
      "alert": {
          "title": "", (“notification_title” will be here)
          "subtitle": "",
          "body": “”(“description” will be here)
      },
      "badge": 1,
      "sound": "default",
      "content-available": 1
  }
}
```

**3. Your notifications will behaviour will be as follows:**

**App is in Foreground**

- No system alert shown
- `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called

**App is in Background**

- System alert is shown
- `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called

**App is in Suspended**

- App state changes to Background
- System alert is shown
- `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is called

**App is Not Running because killed by user**

- System alert is shown
- No callback is called

Comment: this solves a different problem doesn't it? the payload key is already in the APN. background fetch is when you have content > 4kb (5kb for VOIP APNs) -- in that case, you don't send a payload, you send a url. He's setting a key called "payload", and it is not in UserInfo afterwards (Although the apn keys are there)